# MongoDB Morphia distinct

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

```
public Collection<OwnerDetail> getAllOwners() {
    final MorphiaCursor<Listing> listings = datastore.find(Listing.class)
            .iterator(new FindOptions()
                    .projection().include("ownerDetail"));

    Map<String, OwnerDetail> map = new HashMap<>();

    while (listings.hasNext()) {
        final Listing next = listings.next();
        if (next.getOwnerDetail() != null) {
            map.put(next.getOwnerDetail().getEmail(), next.getOwnerDetail());
        }
    }
    return map.values();
}
```

I want to remove java code that distinct values by email and handle it by mongodb morphia. How can I do that?

Comment: Hope this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12481678/2987755

Comment: Raw mongodb query in morphia: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53723927/2987755, or https://morphia.dev/morphia/2.2/aggregations.html